# Need help including multiple jQuery effects in a scroll 'else' statement

Tags: jquery, function, scroll, slide

Can't figure this one out. I am intermediate with jQuery but am having trouble.

```
   <div class="some-div"></div>
<div class="monster"></div>
<div class="another-div"></div>
<div class="little-nav">
    <p>click me!</p>
</div>
<div class="list">
    <p>close!</p>
</div>
<div class="div3">
</div>
```

My jQuery is as follows:

```
var subNavTop = $('.monster').offset().top;
var littleNav = $('.little-nav');
var slideButton = $('.little-nav p');
var list = $('.list');
var closeList = $('.list p');

$(window).scroll(function() {
        //if window is scrolled to top of 'monster'
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > subNavTop) {

            littleNav.slideDown('fast');

            slideButton.click(function(){
            littleNav.fadeOut('slow');
            list.stop().animate({left: '0px'});
            });

            closeList.click(function(){
            list.stop().animate({left: '-200px'});
            littleNav.fadeIn('slow');
            });

        }

        else {
            littleNav.slideUp('fast');
        }
});
```

I have a fixed sub-nav that appears when the user scrolls to a certain point on the page.  I have successfully been able to slide in and slide out the nav if user scrolls back up.  However, I have other pop-out menus within this nav.  Everything is working fine, except if the user scrolls to the sub-nav, opens a pop-out, and doesn't close it then the nav remains on the page when scrolled back up.  I have included all of this here http://jsfiddle.net/jbarbermerge/pb9zwcx0/.  Can someone please help me close the .little-nav when the user srolls back up if the .list is still open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to just test to see if the user is still scrolled to the appropriate spot before showing the `little-nav` again. Demonstration at [my fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yc025z3g/2).

Relevant change:

```
closeList.click(function(){
    list.stop().animate({left: '-200px'});
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > subNavTop) {
        littleNav.fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

As a side note, it's best to bind your event handlers only once. Weird things can happen when you bind events inside other event handlers, especially the `scroll` event which gets fired quite often. Since your elements aren't dynamically created or destroyed and their behavior doesn't change dynamically, the click event handlers should be defined as soon as the corresponding elements are declared. Here's what I mean:

```
    var subNavTop = $('.monster').offset().top;
    var littleNav = $('.little-nav');
    var slideButton = $('.little-nav p');
    var list = $('.list');
    var closeList = $('.list p');

    closeList.click(function(){
        list.stop().animate({left: '-200px'});
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > subNavTop) {
            littleNav.fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });

    slideButton.click(function(){
        littleNav.fadeOut('slow');
        list.stop().animate({left: '0px'});
    });

    $(window).scroll(function() { // ...
```

You'll notice that these handlers don't refer to anything that would only be known during the scroll. In general, if you *do* require information from the surrounding event to determine the correct behavior, you'll need a more careful approach.

Another observation is that, regardless of whether the Nav object is currently visible, the `slideDown` function is called every time the window scrolls. I think jQuery does the right thing (i.e. nothing) with this, but it's a possible source of bugs, which I noticed when updating my fiddle to remove the list whenever the user scrolls back up.

Basically, to handle these cases, I added two booleans to global scope: `isNavVisible` and `isListVisible`. This is basically just caching the value of `element.is(":visible")` and using it to determine whether the given animation needs to take place. Without these checks, I would see the `slideUp` animation on the (supposedly faded out) Nav bar whenever the list was dismissed. This is because every time a scroll takes place below the cut-off point, the nav bar is revealed. We just don't see it when the list is up because it lies on top of the nav bar.

Comment: Don't forget to move the `click` handlers outside of the `scroll` handler, otherwise you'll be binding the same event thousands of times.

Comment: Austin, thanks for the response.  That definitely makes sense to make sure the event handlers are only binded once.  Your response is definitely helping me, however...the updated fiddle still does not do what I am looking for.  You'll notice in the fiddle you posted that if you scroll down, click to open the 'list' and then scroll back up, the list remains on the screen.  I would like for the list to slide back out if the user scrolls back up past the point where 'little-nav' opens.  Can you help me with that.  Thanks a ton for your response.  Lots of good pointers in there.

Comment: I had no idea you wanted that behavior. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Updated with revision 2.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  Not only answered my question, but gave me some very useful tips for the future!